# Spark out of memory with a large number of window functions (lag, lead)

Tags: apache-spark, window-functions

I need to calculate additional features from a dataset using multiple lead's and lag's. The high number of lead's and lag's causes a out-of-memory error.

Data frame:

```
|----------+----------------+---------+---------+-----+---------|
| DeviceID | Timestamp      | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | ... | Sensor9 |
|----------+----------------+---------+---------+-----+---------|
|          |                |         |         |     |         |
| Long     | Unix timestamp | Double  | Double  |     | Double  |
|          |                |         |         |     |         |
|----------+----------------+---------+---------+-----+---------|
```

Window definition:

```
// Each window contains about 600 rows
val w = Window.partitionBy("DeviceID").orderBy("Timestamp")
```

Compute extra features:

```
var res = df
val sensors = (1 to 9).map(i => s"Sensor$i")

for (i <- 1 to 5) {
  for (s <- sensors) {
    res = res.withColumn(lag(s, i).over(w))
         .withColumn(lead(s, i)).over(w)
  }

  // Compute features from all the lag's and lead's
  [...]
}
```

System info:

```
RAM: 16G
JVM heap: 11G
```

The code gives correct results with small datasets, but gives an out-of-memory error with 10GB of input data. 
I think the culprit is the high number of window functions because the DAG shows a very long sequence of

```
Window -> WholeStageCodeGen -> Window -> WholeStageCodeGen ...
```

Is there anyway to calculate the same features in a more efficient way? 
For example, is it possible to get lag(Sensor1, 1), lag(Sensor2, 1), ..., lag(Sensor9, 1) without calling lag(..., 1) nine times?

If the answer to the previous question is no, then how can I avoid out-of-memory? I have already tried increasing the number of partitions.

Comment: never heard of `groupBy` on `Window`, do you mean `partitionBy`?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth : Yes, I meant partitionBy. I have edited the question to reflex this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
res = res.select('*', lag(s"Sensor$1", 1).over(w), lag(s"Sensor$1", 2).over(w), ...)
```

That is, to write everything in a `select` instead of many `withColumn`

Then there will be only 1 Window in the plan. Maybe it helps with the performance.